# Why isn't my SOAP request working?

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP request with PHP. It seems my request matches the request detailed in the SOAP server's documentation (but with slightly different methods), yet I'm getting an authentication error, as if the header is not being included.

The documentation's request sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://novosolutions.com/">
      <SessionId>string</SessionId>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ViewTicket xmlns="http://novosolutions.com/">
      <Id>int</Id>
    </ViewTicket>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The request my PHP code outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://novosolutions.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:AuthHeader>
            <SessionId>623</SessionId>
        </ns1:AuthHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ViewTicket>
            <Id>1355110</Id>
        </ns1:ViewTicket>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My PHP code is rather simple. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$url = URL_BASE . URL_TICKET . '?WSDL';
$soapStruct = new SoapVar(array('SessionId' => SESSION_ID), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header = new SoapHeader('http://novosolutions.com/', 'AuthHeader', $soapStruct, false);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));
}
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo 'Exception='.$exception;
}
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
var_dump($client);

$soapData = new SoapVar(array('Id' => 1355110), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$result = $client->__soapCall('ViewTicket', array('parameters' => $soapData));

var_dump($result);
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

EDIT:
By testing the request with a curl, I've narrowed it down to the fact that PHP's SoapClient uses a variable for the namespace.  is not accepted by the SoapServer, but  is. Now I just need to figure out how to prevent SoapClient from using variables.

Comment: Could you find a solution yet? I got the exact problem.

Comment: Yes - I was including the wrong # for the session id. The session id was in the response header not the response body. To get it, use $responseHeaders = array();
$result = $client->__soapCall('Login', array('parameters' => $bodyVar), null, null, $responseHeaders);
$sessionid = $responseHeaders['AuthHeader']->SessionId;

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply try this ?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$client = new SoapClient($url,array('trace' => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders( new SoapHeader($url, 'SessionId', SESSION_ID) );
$result = $client->ViewTicket(array('Id'=>1355110));
var_dump($result);
echo '<hr>',str_replace('<','&lt;',$client->__getLastRequest());
```

What kind of error message does it produce ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No PHP error - the result is the same (Authentication error or session is expired). Result: http://codepad.org/EbQnxKO3

Comment: I try the same request with soapUI software (get it free at http://www.soapui.org) , i got the same result (Authentication error or session is expired)... Are you sure it does not require credentials ? (like a user/pwd HTTP header) ?

Comment: I've almost got it- do you know how to prevent PHP's SoapClient from using variables for namespaces? I need <Login xmlns="http://novosolutions.com/"> instead of <ns1:Login>

Comment: You can build a class extension and use a preg_replace to do the job, like they explain in : http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=326228.0